# Is there a way to achieve the visual effect of stacking the element of one stacking context in-between the elements of another stacking context?

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid, z-index, mix-blend-mode

I have this grid where each cell is a relatively positioned parent of an absolutely positioned div element that itself can be either a value containing div element or a wrapper element of one such relatively positioned value element, e.g.:

```
<div id="my-grid">
  <div class="base">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="value">abc</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="base">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="value">def</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  ..
</div>
```

A wrapper element and its child can overflow the cells without value on their right. It is imperative for each value or wrapper element to have its background set so that it covers the backgrounds of the underlying base elements (its own and, if overflowing, of any cell on its right).

Now, each cell may occasionally have another element in its hierarchy (a "patch" element) of the same size and position of the base element (i.e. never overflowing) that, when visible, should be visually stacked in-between any wrapper (background) and its child (text value) that happen to be visually placed at the same position in the grid, whether of the cell of the patch or some other overflowing cell on its left.

The only way that comes to mind is to flatten all the wrappers and patches so they become siblings and as such the parts of a same stacking context, but this is unacceptable for many reasons.

I am open to different design/refactoring suggestions. Also, I think I saw somewhere that elements in a flex container can be visually interleaved with elements of another flex container but couldn't reproduce the effect for this purpose.

PS. Also tried different experiments with mix blending but the results were visually unsatisfactory.

Comment: please provide a minimum reproducible code snippet with your html+css so we can take a deeper look.

Comment: It won't be of any use for the problem is not the code, but the approach. I need a conceptual answer on how to get the visual effect of z-stacking a non-sibling element between a parent (wrapper) and a child (the value), or a completely different solution altogether but with the same visual result.

Comment: I am aware of that but, given how child/parent relationships work in css - before getting into z stacking, having a baseline of where you are starting from would narrow down the options to a concrete answer.

Comment: @Capagris
Here's a sample code:
https://codepen.io/damir_p/pen/xxRQery

The first cell with the Lorem ipsum text is overflowing to the right over the cell #2 and partially over the cell #3. The cell #3 happens to have this patch element that is desired to be stacked in-between the cell #1 wrapper and value elements. If the cell #3 had any value itself, the cell #1 would only overflow the cell #2, and the cell #3 would have its own background then (in case its text overflows to the right).
In either case, the patch element should be visually z-stacked in between a  background and its text.

Comment: PS. JS can only be used with respect to the patch since it comes and goes dynamically, while the cells get rendered and are static until the contents changes.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I know of a workaround solution but it's too lame in my opinion.
https://codepen.io/damir_p/pen/mdOvKoR
The thing is to have have the background and text elements as two siblings in the same flex container. The "only" problem is having all the text rendered twice (times hundreds/thousands of cells per page)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the real solution:
https://codepen.io/damir_p/pen/XWNOPea

```
#b1 {
  &:before {
    @include cell;
    @include abspos;
    z-index: $z-background;
    content: attr( data-value);
    background-color: yellow;
    color: transparent;
    min-width: max-content;
  }
  &:after {
    @include cell;
    @include abspos;
    content: attr( data-value);
    z-index: $z-value;
  }
}
```

Essentially it comes down to using an attribute in the base div element and then its two pseudo classes for the background and the text value while for the patch element it is best to remain a standard div.